# Add addeventlistener to a nodelist

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-objects

I am trying to add a click `eventListener` to some div HTML elements with same class, but I cannot click on my cells when the game is initialized. I am quite new in JS. Any suggestion or hint to point me in the right direction? T

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");
let gameMark = function(cell) {
  if (gameActive == true) {
    let player = playerTurn();
    let position = parseInt(cell.id[cell.id.length - 1]);
    cell.innerText = player.symb;
    boardArray.array[position] = player.symb;
    gameWin();
    gameTie();
  }
};

cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', gameMark(cell)));
```

```html
<strike>
<section id="board">
        <div id="gameContainer">
            <div id="row1">
                <div id="cell_0" class="cell"></div>
                <div id="cell_1" class="cell"></div>
                <div id="cell_2" class="cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="row2">
                <div id="cell_3" class="cell"></div>
                <div id="cell_4" class="cell"></div>
                <div id="cell_5" class="cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="row3">
                <div id="cell_6" class="cell"></div>
                <div id="cell_7" class="cell"></div>
                <div id="cell_8" class="cell"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </section>
</strike>
```

Comment: I moved your code into a code snippet, please add the necessary code to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) expects a function as it's second parameter. You're passing the *result* of function call.

```
                                // calling the function--+ 
                                //                       |
cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', gameMark(cell)));
```

---

You would need to either change `gameMark` to return a function:

```
let gameMark = function(cell) {
    return function () {
        if (gameActive == true) {
            let player = playerTurn();
            let position = parseInt(cell.id[cell.id.length - 1]);
            cell.innerText = player.symb;
            boardArray.array[position] = player.symb;
            gameWin();
            gameTie();
        }
    }
};
```

or use anonymous function in the loop:

```
cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', function () {
  gameMark(cell);
});
```